# Hazelcast serialization issue with multiple nodes

Tags: java, serialization, parallel-processing, hazelcast

I have issue with HZ. I m using Entry Processor to run complex calculations. Those calculations use multiple IMaps. I have used PartitionAware to provide logic for controlled partition storing of data.  I need to ensure that all required for calculations records from different maps are on same partition. Also I m passing hzinstance object to Entry Processor.So now I met new issue: I m able to run calculations with one member cluster. But once I will add second instance - I m start facing errors related to serialization of HazelcastInstanceProxy or Entry Processor, or UUID, or CuncurrentHashMap. I was trying to use CompactSerializer, java default serializer and both gives same result. I m using EP, coz it much faster than execution task. Can anybody help me understand what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So, solution was very simple. I just had to add `transient` keyword for HazelcastInstance variable. Also Entry Processor should implement `HazelcastInstanceAware` interface. It will provide setter to instance. There is no necessity to direct injection of instance. Hz will do it by itself on its side once EP would be deserialised there.